# Swift completion in defer

Tags: swift, deferred, completionhandler

I like defer, because in complex functions with multi-case scenario, I can't forget calling completion before the function ends.

But when the completion is passed to another function, it shouldn't be run in first function's defer.

This is what I usually do:

```swift
func doSomething(completion: ()->()) {
    /// Set this to false, before passing the completion to another function.
    var runCompletionInDefer = true
    defer {
        if runCompletionInDefer { completion() }
    }
    runCompletionInDefer = false
    doSomethingElse { completion() }
}

func doSomethingElse(completion: ()->()) {
    completion()
}
```

Is there a better solution?

With this approach, before passing the completion to another function, you still must remember to do:

```swift
runCompletionInDefer = false
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should put code into `defer` until you are positive that you actually want to execute that code every single time you reach the end of your function.

So let me suggest that maybe what you actually want to `defer` is not so much the literal execution of your completion closure, but a rather a check that gives you confidence that the completion closure has been called somewhere by someone by the time `defer` is reached. An "execution receipt" of sorts.

To do that, one could wrap the closure into a structure that keeps track of it's execution. Here is an example how such a wrapper could look like:

```
protocol CompletionReceiptProtocol {
    associatedtype Closure: Any
    var receipt: Bool { get }
    func execute()
}

class SomethingCompletion: CompletionReceiptProtocol {
    typealias Closure = (()->Void)

    var receipt = false
    private var closure: Closure

    init(_ closure: @escaping Closure) {
        self.closure = closure
    }

    func execute() {
        self.closure()
        self.receipt = true
    }

}
```

And here is how you would use the wrapper:

```
func doSomething(completion nakedCompletion: @escaping ()->Void) {
    let completion = SomethingCompletion(nakedCompletion)
    defer {
        assert(completion.receipt , "Oops! End of function reached without completion being called!") // or whatever error handling or logging you want to do in that case
    }

    // Scenario A: `doSomething` executes the completion itself
    completion.execute()

    // Scenario B: `doSomething` delegates the completion to `doSomethingElse`...
    doSomethingElse(completion: completion)
}

func doSomethingElse(completion: SomethingCompletion) {
    completion.execute() //... and it's called here instead. So it's all good!
}
```

Comment: What happens if the defer runs before the completion? Imagine that doSomethingElse is an asynchronous task, then the assertion will fail, I don't want that.

Comment: Yes, sure. I guess if there is more asynchronicity down the line, instead of only issuing the receipt on execution, you could e.g. also issue one already on "handing over" the closure to a delegate (which would ideally have it's own mechanism in place to guarantee either transfer or execution).